# Transforming JSON to nested ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json

I have a JSON block that I want to convert to a ruby hash.

`json_blob = {"WHATEVER"=>{"FOO"=>"BAR", "CAT"=>"DAY}}`

so that when I am using the data, I can check whether the data is there.  Example:

`hashed_json_blob[:whatever][:foo]` returns `"bar"`

and also, I could handle values that don't exist either (they were omitted in the json_blob).

`hashed_json_blob[:whatever][:nonexistant]` returns `nil`

Note: if there is an easier way with the data as XML, that can work to.  The `json_blob` was pulled using `JSON.parse`

Comment: Amit doesn't seem to answer your question as you've already mentioned JSON.parse. Could you explain a little bit more about what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your json_blob object is *already* a hash (minus one missing quote at the end of "DAY"):

```
json_blob = {"WHATEVER"=>{"FOO"=>"BAR", "CAT"=>"DAY"}}
```

with this you can do:

```
json_blob["WHATEVER"]
=> {"FOO"=>"BAR", "CAT"=>"DAY"}

json_blob["WHATEVER"]["FOO"]
=> "BAR"
```

The same data as a json object would look like this:

```
{"WHATEVER":{"FOO":"BAR","CAT":"DAY"}}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just didn't think of it that way, and this pretty much solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`gem install json`

`require 'json'`

`json_blob = {"WHATEVER"=>{"FOO"=>"BAR", "CAT"=>"DAY}}`

`abc = JSON.parse(json_blob)`

now you can perform operations on `abc`

Comment: That is how I got my XML to JSON format. As far as I know, I thought that just `JSON.parse` returned JSON

Comment: your string should be in correct json format and then using `JSON.parse` you can use it as `hashed_json_blob[:whatever][:foo]`